# Concerns formalizing a "Minimal Element" proof by contradiction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, first-order-logic

I came across an exercise where my proposed solution strikes me as a little informal/hand-wavy at the end. I was hoping that someone could lend a hand!

Consider the set $A$ and two subsets of $A$,  $a\downarrow$ and $b\downarrow$, defined as follows:

$a\downarrow := \{x \in A | xRa\}$

$b\downarrow := \{x \in A | x R b\}$

Of importance, $R$ is **well-ordered** on $A$ (and any subset of $A$). Specifically, that means trichotomy, transitivity, irreflexivity, and well-foundedness are properties of $R$.

**The aim of this proof is to demonstrate that if $a \neq b$ then no isomorphism $k$ exists such that $(b \downarrow;R) \cong (a \downarrow; R)$.**

---

I proceed by contradiction and assume that such an isomorphism exists: call it $k: b \downarrow \to a \downarrow$.

**W**ithout **L**oss of **G**enerality, let $a \downarrow \subset b \downarrow$. This is a consequence of trichotomy: either $aRb, bRa,$ or $a=b$. Choose $aRb$...thus $a \in b\downarrow$ but $a \notin a\downarrow$.

To demonstrate that $a\downarrow$ is a **proper subset**, pick an element $x \in a\downarrow$. By definition, $xRa$. But we know that $aRb$. Therefore, by transitivity of $R$, $xRb \implies x \in b \downarrow$.

Additionally, the definition of these sets prohibits $b \downarrow$ from containing elements that are "beneath" the minimal element of $a \downarrow$ (quick proof by contradiction).

---

Because $k$ is an isomorphism, it is surjective. Therefore, looking at the minimal element in $a \downarrow$, call it $m$, there are two possible categories of mappings:

**Case 1**) An element $x \in b\downarrow$ such that $mRx$, and $x$ gets mapped to $m \in a \downarrow$ through $k$.

$$k(x)=m$$

**Case 2**) $m \in b \downarrow$ gets mapped to $m \in a \downarrow$ through $k$.

$$k(m)=m$$

---

**Case 1 results in a contradiction: order will not be preserved**

If $k(x)=m$, where $mRx$, then there is a $y \in b \downarrow$ such that $yRx$. This $y$ must be mapped to some element in $a \downarrow$, call it $s$. So we have:

$$k(x)=m \land k(y)=s$$

$yRx$ but $[k(x)=m] \ R \  [s=k(y)]$. The order was flipped! Contradiction.

---

$\color{red}{\text{Case 2 is where I feel like my argument is hand-wavy}}$

We have $k(m)=m$. That is to say, the $m \in b\downarrow$ is being mapped to the $m \in a \downarrow$. Now consider the following algorithm:

Choose the element $n$ in $a \downarrow$ such that the following is true: $\forall z( z\in a\downarrow \setminus \{m\} \rightarrow nRz \lor n=z)$. You can view this $n$ as the "the next minimal element".

Notice that there are two subcases of possible mappings from elements of $b \downarrow$ to $n \in a\downarrow$ :

**Subcase 1**) An element $x \in b\downarrow$ such that $nRx$ gets mapped to $n \in a \downarrow$ through $k$.

$$k(x)=n$$

**Subcase 2**) $n \in b \downarrow$ gets mapped to $n \in a \downarrow$ through $k$.

$$k(n)=n$$

But this is just a "slightly different" version of the argument we encountered earlier with $m$.

This continues to repeat until you've run out of elements in $a \downarrow$ but are still left with $a \in b \downarrow$, which will have no where to map to without violating injectivity and ordering. Therefore, no such isomorphism $k$ exists.

---

That final piece of the argument, where I say," **This continues to repeat...**," strikes me as unsatisfactorily informal. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Cheers~

Comment: Comment: your definition of Case 1 seems to be missing stuff; I think you mean "such that $mRx$ *and* $k(x)=m$". In your contradiction argument for Case 1, why bother introducing an existential $y$? Just use $m$ itself, which you are already assuming satisfies $mRx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right that it’s hand-wavy at that point: what you have is an *and so on* argument. You can convert it to a genuine *minimum counterexample* argument like this.

Since $a\!\downarrow\subsetneqq b\!\downarrow$, it’s clear that $\{x\in b\!\downarrow:k(x)\ne x\}\ne\varnothing$. Let

$$m=\min\{x\in b\!\downarrow:k(x)\ne x\}\,.$$

Then $k(x)=x$ for each $x\in m\!\downarrow$, so $k(m)\notin m\!\downarrow$. And by construction $k(m)\ne m$, so $m\mathrel{R}k(m)$. Now show that $m\notin\operatorname{ran}k$.

Comment: Awesome. I'll mull over this a bit. Thank you!

Comment: @S.Cramer: You’re welcome!

Comment: I finally got around to thinking about your response...and I follow it all the way until the very last statement: $m^{+} \notin \text{ran}\ k$. I'm not quite sure how exactly you produce that particular statement. The contradiction that I use (which includes all of your work up to, and including, $m\  R \ k(m)$) is the notion that $m$ must satisfy one of the following two cases: $m \in a \downarrow \lor (m \in b \downarrow \land m \notin a\downarrow)$. If $m \in a \downarrow$, then you can show that $k$ does not preserve order with respect to $R$.

Comment: For the case where $m \in b \downarrow \land m \notin a \downarrow$, I claim that such a statement means that $m \downarrow = a \downarrow$...but given that $m \ R\ k(m)$ we have a contradiction...because $k(m) \in a \downarrow$ but $m \notin a \downarrow$...knowing that $a \downarrow$ is an initial segment, this cannot be the case. I think these are sound arguments...so I am sort of curious as to how you arrived at the statement: $m^{+} \notin \text {ran} \ k$

Comment: @S.Cramer: Argh! That was a typo: it should have said that $m\notin\operatorname{ran}k$. This is clear: everything below $m$ goes to itself under $k$, $m$ goes to something bigger than itself, and $k$ is order-preserving, so everything bigger than $m$ must go to something bigger than $k(m)$.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

What you call a "well order" is actually a *strict* well order (in my experience, most people take the non-strict version of (partial) orders as the primitive notion, hence the one without qualifier).

1. Your argument that $a\downarrow$ is a proper subset of $b\downarrow$ is not well written. The first part, that $a\downarrow\neq b\downarrow$ is not motivated and just comes out of nowhere. It should be after the statement that $a\downarrow$ is a proper subset.
2. There's a typo in your first enunciation of case 1: $mRx$ is not mapped anywhere, as it is a statement of relation (that is, that $(m,x)\in R$). You mean $x$ is such that $mRx$ (which under your definition implies $m\neq x$), **and** that $x$ is mapped to $m$ via $k$.
3. Your contradiction argument for case 1... why not use $m$ directly? You already know $mRx$. So you would get $k(m)R m$, which is impossible since $m$ is the least element of $a\downarrow$.

---

There is a way of doing your algorithm without doing your algorithm by instead describing the sets that are results of your algorithm. This is the same idea that George Bergman uses in his [handout with a proof of Zorn's Lemma](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/grad.hndts/AC+Zorn+.ps) (the link is to a PostScript file). Though Brian Scott has given a way to get around it, I thought it might be instructive to show this for your argument.

You could describe the sets you get "along the way" as follows:

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the collection of all subsets $T$ of $A$ with the following properties:

1. $m\in T$ (that is, $T\neq\varnothing$).
2. $T$ is an initial segment of $A$ (that is, if $y\in T$ and $xRy$, then $x\in T$).
3. $T\subseteq a\downarrow$ and $T\subseteq b\downarrow$.
4. The restriction of $k$ to $T$ is the identity map.

Note that $\mathscr{C}$ is nonempty, since $\{m\}$ itself is an element of $\mathscr{C}$, as we are in case 2.

These are, essentially, the sets you get at the end of each "step" of your algorithm.

Now, if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two elements of $\mathscr{C}$, then either $T_1\subseteq T_2$ or $T_2\subseteq T_1$. Indeed, if $T_1$ is not contained in $T_2$, let $x\in T_1$, $x\notin T_2$. If $y\in T_2$, then we must have $yRx$ (if $xRy$, then $x\in T_2$ as $T_2$ is an initial segment). But then $y\in T_1$, as $T_1$ is an initial segment; hence $T_2\subseteq T_1$.

Let $U=\cup\mathscr{C}$. Then $m\in U$; $U$ is an initial segment of $A$; $U\subseteq a\downarrow$ and $U\subseteq b\downarrow$; and $k$ restricted to $U$ is the identity map. (I'll leave you to check the details).

That is, $U\in\mathscr{C}$. I claim that $U=a\downarrow$. Indeed, if $U$ is a proper initial segment of $a\downarrow$, then let $y$ be the least element of $(a\downarrow)\setminus U$; this is also the least element of $(b\downarrow) \setminus U$, and so using the argument like you did, we must have $k(y)=y$. Then $U\cup\{y\}\in\mathscr{C}$, but $y\notin U$, a contradiction. Thus, $U=a\downarrow$.

That means that $k$, restricted to the *proper* subset $a\downarrow$ of $b\downarrow$, is the identity map; hence it is already surjective. But then $k(a)=k(x)$ for some $x\in a\downarrow$, which contradicts the assumption that $k$ is one-to-one.

Comment: Thank you for the input! It's going to take a while to digest but I'm looking forward to it. I'll make the correction to Case 1 that you correctly pointed out. Cheers~

Comment: It took a while, but I think I nearly fully understand the argument. Why, however, do you need to stipulate Property $1$: $m \in T$? I couldn't wrap my head around that. Aren't I 'begging the question' by requiring Property $1$? Shouldn't I, instead, use properties 2-4 to demonstrate that $\{m\}$ necessarily must be an element of $\mathscr{C}$...which is actually what I do in "Case 1". Once I show that $\{m\} \in \mathscr{C}$, then I can use your strategy to demonstrate that $U=a \downarrow \in \mathscr{C}$

Comment: @S.Cramer: The idea is to describe what a completed set in your “and so on” steps look like. Since we start the “and so on” process by selecting $m$, we state that the sets contain $m$. No, you aren’t begging the question (which would be to assume the conclusion you want, namely that there is no bijection). You cannot use properties 2, 3, and 4 to deduce Property 1, because the empty set satisfies properties 2, 3, and 4, but not property 1. You could deduce it from 2 if you assume $T$ is nonempty, but why add the extra step? Just say $m$ is in $T$.

Comment: @S.Cramer: Note also that this is the argument for your Case 2, after you’ve established that $m$ must map to $m$.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up; why is it problematic that the empty set be in $\mathscr C$? Is it because we do not know if $\emptyset \in A$?

Comment: @S.Cramer: I didn’t say it was problematic: I said the empty set satisfies 2-4 and not 1, so 1 cannot be deduced from just 2-4 (as you said you would want to try to do). Again: the idea here is to describe what the sets that your “and so on” process produce at the end of each step as completed objects (so that you don’t have to set up an induction over an unknown index set). Since all such sets include $m$, our description should also include $m$. You do not obtain the empty set in your process at any step, so our description of these sets should not include it either.