# How do I create the set necessary to prove the following statement: If $X$ is a non-empty set of ordinals, then $\bigcup X = \text{sup}(X)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, ordinals

In the following paragraphs, I will outline my proof for the claim:

> If $X$ is a non-empty set of ordinals, then $\bigcup X = \text{sup}(X)$

I've taken note of the post here ([$\bigcup X$ = $\sup(X)$ for a set $X$ of ordinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537654/bigcup-x-supx-for-a-set-x-of-ordinals)),**but my question is NOT related to "How Do I Prove This"**.

---

I have included my proof of this statement for reference...but for the **actual question**, you can scroll to the bottom.

---

This proof amounts to demonstrating that $\bigcup X$ is the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\alpha \geq \xi$ for all $\xi \in X$.

At the end of my proof, I will clarify the specifics of my question.

As an important side note, my book (*The Foundations of Mathematics* By Kenneth Kunen) uses the following conventions:

> When discussing ordinals, Greek letters (especially $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \zeta, \eta, \xi, \mu$) "range over the ordinals"; that is, $\forall \alpha \varphi(\alpha)$ abbreviates $$ \forall x [x \text{ is an ordinal} \rightarrow \varphi(x)] $$ Also, $\alpha \lt \beta$ means (by definition) $\alpha \in \beta$, and $\alpha \leq \beta$ means $\alpha \in \beta \lor \alpha = \beta$

Also, the following definition will be used:

> Let $R$ be a relation. $y \in X$ is $R$-maximal in $X$ iff $\neg \exists z (z \in X \land yRx))$

---

This proof is broken up into two parts:

Part $1$: Demonstrate that $\neg \exists \zeta (\zeta \lt \bigcup X \land \forall \alpha (\alpha \in X \rightarrow \alpha \leq \zeta ))$

Part $2$: Demonstrate that $\bigcup X$ satisfies the property that $\forall \alpha ( \alpha \in X \rightarrow \alpha \leq \bigcup X)$

The following lemmas are useful:

> $\bigcup X$ is an ordinal

> $\alpha \text{ is an ordinal } \land \delta \in \alpha \rightarrow \delta \text{ is an ordinal}$

---

Part $1$: Proof by Contradiction - show that $\exists \zeta (\zeta \lt \bigcup X \land \forall \alpha (\alpha \in X \rightarrow \alpha \leq \zeta ))$ leads to a contradiction.

By definition, $\bigcup X = \{ \alpha \in A \  | \ \exists \beta (\beta  \in X \land \alpha \in \beta)\}$ where $A$ is the set that is posited to exist by my book's **Union Axiom**.

Let $\xi$ be an ordinal that satisfies the claim we want to produce a contradiction with.

Therefore, $\xi \in \bigcup X$. By definition of $\bigcup X$, this implies that $\exists \beta (\beta \in X \land \xi \in \beta)$. Call this object $\beta'$.

But $\xi \in \beta' \iff \xi \lt \beta'$ means that there is an ordinal in $X$ (i.e. $\beta'$) that is strictly greater than $\xi$...a contradiction. Therefore,  $\neg \exists \zeta (\zeta \lt \bigcup X \land \forall \alpha (\alpha \in X \rightarrow \alpha \leq \zeta ))$

---

Part $2$:

Let $\alpha \in X$.

Show that either $\alpha \in \bigcup X$ or $\alpha = \bigcup X$.

There are two scenarios that are possible with respect to $\alpha$:

i) $\alpha$ is not $R$-maximal in $X$ $\iff \exists \beta ( \beta \in X \land \alpha \in \beta)$

ii) $\alpha$ is $R$-maximal in $X$ $\iff \neg \exists \beta (\beta \in X \land \alpha \in \beta)$

---

*Scenario i*: Prove that $\alpha \in \bigcup X$

By definition of $\bigcup X$, if $\exists \beta ( \beta \in X \land \alpha \in \beta)$ then $\alpha \in \bigcup X$.

---

*Scenario ii*: Prove that $\alpha = \bigcup X$ (i.e. prove that they are subsets of each other)

Let $\gamma \in \alpha$. By definition of $\bigcup X$, $\gamma \in \bigcup X$. Therefore, $\alpha \subseteq \bigcup X$.

Let $\gamma \in \bigcup X$. By definition of $\bigcup X$, $\exists \beta (\beta \in X \land \gamma \in \beta)$. Call this $\beta^*$. (i.e. $\gamma \in \beta^*$)

$\alpha$ is maximal and $\beta^* \in X$. By **trichotomy of ordinals**, $\beta^* \leq \alpha$.

Breaking this into two cases:

a) $\beta^* \lt \alpha \iff \beta^* \in \alpha$. Therefore, because $\beta^*$ is an ordinal, $\beta^* \subset \alpha$. But that means $\gamma \in \alpha$. Thus, $\bigcup X \subseteq \alpha$.

b) $\beta^*=\alpha$. Well, in such a case, it is immediately clear that $\gamma \in \alpha$. Thus, $\bigcup X \subseteq \alpha$.

---

I believe what I carried out above is correct and demonstrates that

> If $X$ is a non-empty set of ordinals, then $\bigcup X = \text{sup}(X)$

**My question is as follows**:

Throughout this proof, it dawned on me that what I am effectively *doing* with my argument is creating a set that looks like this:

$\{\eta\in ON \ | \forall \alpha (\alpha \in X \rightarrow \alpha \leq \eta) \}$ (...where $ON$ is the set of all ordinals...)

and subsequently proving that $\bigcup X$ must be the minimal element of this set.

After doing a little digging, I found that $ON$ is **not a set**, and actually forms a **Proper Class**, which means that the notation "$\eta \in ON$" is invalid syntax in formal set theory.

How then should I describe the aforementioned set?

The only thing I can think to do is the following:

$\{\eta\in S(\bigcup X) \ | \forall \alpha (\alpha \in X \rightarrow \alpha \leq \eta) \}$

Where $S(\bigcup X)=\bigcup X \cup \{\bigcup X\}$

**Is this the proper convention** (or at least acceptable in and of itself?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern is unfounded: you are not looking at some set of ordinals and showing that $\bigcup X$ is the least element of that set. The axioms ensure the existence of the set $\bigcup X$, and you have presumably proved that $\bigcup X$ is an ordinal. Now you are simply showing $(1)$ that $X$ has no upper bound that is less than the ordinal $\bigcup X$, and $(2)$ that $\bigcup X$ is an upper bound for $X$. It follows immediately from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $\bigcup X=\sup X$.

It’s true that once you’ve shown that $\bigcup X=\sup X$, you get as an immediate corollary that $\bigcup X=\min Y$ whenever $Y$ is a non-empty set of upper bounds for $X$, but the proof that $\bigcup X=\sup X$ does not make use of any such $Y$.

Comment: Hmmmm. Out of curiosity (if this question even makes sense), when WOULD a proof "make use of any such $Y$"? Is there key language that informs the seasoned Mathster, "Oh, I need to make a set and find the minimal element". After the method that Arturo Magidin showed me here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3941977/concerns-formalizing-a-minimal-element-proof-by-contradiction), which is a post that you actually commented on, I sort of began developing a feeling that all formal arguments are just alternate representations of very specific set constructions.

Comment: (that is why I posed this question in the first place)

Comment: @S.Cramer: Many arguments fall into more of less familiar patterns and make use of similar constructions, but there’s a lot more variety than ‘alternate representations of very specific set constructions’ suggests. I can’t give you a general rule for picking out contexts in which finding the minimum element of an appropriate set would be a good idea, but one pointer is the kind of setting that you had in that earlier problem: you have an iterative argument that seems to be ‘chasing a goal’ and makes you want to say *and so on*. Often the trick is to ‘jump to the end’ by finding the first ...

Comment: ... point at which everything of interest has been accomplished.